# mysql Trigger for update nex column : Syntax error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i wat to create this trigger to set a defaul value for a clomn but i get this message error : **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4**

this is my script :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_set_content_val BEFORE INSERT
    ON post_table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        set NEW.content = 'mu value here';
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [delimiter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) to something else than semicolon before the stored program and then change it back:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trg_set_content_val 

BEFORE INSERT
    ON post_table
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        set NEW.content = 'mu value here';
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Reason:

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program
>   containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql
>   itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must
>   redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire
>   stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

Comment: In this case pls mark the answer as accepted to let other viewers know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: yes, i'm just waiting 8 min then i can accept the answer :)